# Can't get simple hello world working with next.js/expo (react-native)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

- I generated a new expo/next.js project using the command: `npx create-react-native-app -t with-nextjs`
- I then ran `npm run android`
- I opened the Expo app on my phone
- I scan the QR code
- I see "Open up App.js to start working on your app!"
- I see that `App.js` just has: `export { default } from './pages'`
- I open `pages/index.js` and make some edits:

```
// @generated: @expo/next-adapter@2.1.0
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>This text is not appearing on my phone</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});
```

- I save `App.js`
- Nothing appears to change on my phone.
- I restart the server (`npm run android`)
- Same text on phone

Comment: It started working for some strange reason... I don't know what fixed it, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Simply saving the file will trigger the app to refresh and show the changes.